# Assign the ID created to another column in the Database for URL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a form where it inserts data into the databased.
Name of Link, URL of Link, Title of the page and the content.

However, I want to be able to assign the new ID that gets auto created in both the tables (nav and pages), and put it in url column in the nav table.

Is that possible?

My current insert into database code is below which works fine except for the mentioned question.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Insert'])){

require ("database/connect.php");
$navname = $_POST['navname']; 
$url = $_POST['url']; 
$title = $_POST['title']; 
$pagename = $_POST['pagename']; 
$content = $_POST['content'];
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO nav (name, url, title) VALUES('{$navname}','{$url}','{$title}')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO pages (name, content) VALUES('{$pagename}','{$content}')";
$result = $db->query($sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
$result = $db->query($sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
if($result){
    header("Location: newpage.php?message=1");
}
```

}?>

Comment: Or do I insert as per code above and then call the ID into a form and then update the URL column?  I was hoping there was a way of doing this within the above code  once button submitted, Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO nav (name, url, title) VALUES('{$navname}','{$url}','{$title}')";
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO pages (name, content) VALUES('{$pagename}','{$content}')";
 $result1 = $db->query($sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
 $id1 = $db->insert_id;
 $result2 = $db->query($sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
 $id2 = $db->insert_id;
 // do something to make your url, call it $url, run another mysqli query to update nav.url where id = $id1
```